# Error while fitting data in auto.arima - R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am running auto.arima for forecasting time series data and getting the following error:

> 1: The time series frequency has been rounded to support seasonal
>   differencing.
>   2: In value[3L] :   The chosen test encountered
>   an error, so no seasonal differencing is selected. Check the time
>   series data.

This is what I am executing:

```
fit <- auto.arima(data,seasonal = TRUE, approximation = FALSE)
```

I have weekly time series data.

This is how dput(data) looks like:

```
structure(c(12911647L, 12618317L, 12827388L, 12967840L, 13264925L, 
13557838L, 13701131L, 13812463L, 13971928L, 13837658L, 13550635L, 
13022371L, 13507596L, 13456736L, 12992393L, 12831883L, 13262301L, 
12831691L, 12808893L, 12726330L, 11893457L, 12434051L, 12363464L, 
12077055L, 12107221L, 11986124L, 11997087L, 12264971L, 12164412L, 
12438279L, 12733842L, 12543251L, 12627134L, 12480153L, 12276238L, 
12443655L, 12497753L, 12279060L, 12549138L, 12308591L, 12416680L, 
12516725L, 12326545L, 12772578L, 12524848L, 13429830L, 14188044L, 
16611840L, 16476565L, 15659941L, 10785585L, 12150894L, 13436366L, 
12985213L, 13097555L, 13204872L, 13786040L, 13760281L, 13295389L, 
14734578L, 15043941L, 14821169L, 14361765L, 14300180L, 14357964L, 
14271892L, 13248168L, 13813784L, 14092489L, 14100024L, 13378374L, 
13225650L, 12582444L, 13267163L, 13026181L, 12747286L, 12707074L, 
12534595L, 12546094L, 13030406L, 12950360L, 12814398L, 13405187L, 
13277755L, 13142375L, 12742153L, 12610817L, 12267747L, 12570075L, 
12704157L, 12835948L, 12851893L, 12978880L, 13104906L, 12754018L, 
13213958L, 13584642L, 13963433L, 14471672L, 16312595L, 16630000L, 
16443882L, 11555299L, 12018373L, 13031876L, 13013945L, 13164137L, 
13313246L, 13652605L, 13803606L, 13308310L, 14466211L, 15092736L, 
15346015L, 14467260L, 14767785L, 13914271L, 14185070L, 13851028L, 
13605858L, 13597999L, 13876994L, 13026270L, 13113250L, 12288727L, 
12925846L, 13525010L, 12594472L, 12654512L, 12888260L), .Tsp = c(2016.00819672131, 
2018.48047598209, 52.1785714285714), class = "ts")
```

This is how I am reading data from the csv

```
read_data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE)
data_ts <- ts(read_data, freq=365.25/7,  start=decimal_date(ymd("2016-1-4")))
data <- data_ts[, 2:2]
```

This is the data in the csv:

```
Year    si_act
1/4/16  12911647
1/11/16 12618317
1/18/16 12827388
1/25/16 12967840
2/1/16  13264925
2/8/16  13557838
2/15/16 13701131
2/22/16 13812463
2/29/16 13971928
3/7/16  13837658
3/14/16 13550635
3/21/16 13022371
3/28/16 13507596
4/4/16  13456736
4/11/16 12992393
4/18/16 12831883
4/25/16 13262301
5/2/16  12831691
5/9/16  12808893
5/16/16 12726330
5/23/16 11893457
5/30/16 12434051
6/6/16  12363464
6/13/16 12077055
6/20/16 12107221
6/27/16 11986124
7/4/16  11997087
7/11/16 12264971
7/18/16 12164412
7/25/16 12438279
8/1/16  12733842
8/8/16  12543251
8/15/16 12627134
8/22/16 12480153
8/29/16 12276238
9/5/16  12443655
9/12/16 12497753
9/19/16 12279060
9/26/16 12549138
10/3/16 12308591
10/10/16    12416680
10/17/16    12516725
10/24/16    12326545
10/31/16    12772578
11/7/16 12524848
11/14/16    13429830
11/21/16    14188044
11/28/16    16611840
12/5/16 16476565
12/12/16    15659941
12/19/16    10785585
12/26/16    12150894
1/2/17  13436366
1/9/17  12985213
1/16/17 13097555
1/23/17 13204872
1/30/17 13786040
2/6/17  13760281
2/13/17 13295389
2/20/17 14734578
2/27/17 15043941
3/6/17  14821169
3/13/17 14361765
3/20/17 14300180
3/27/17 14357964
4/3/17  14271892
4/10/17 13248168
4/17/17 13813784
4/24/17 14092489
5/1/17  14100024
5/8/17  13378374
5/15/17 13225650
5/22/17 12582444
5/29/17 13267163
6/5/17  13026181
6/12/17 12747286
6/19/17 12707074
6/26/17 12534595
7/3/17  12546094
7/10/17 13030406
7/17/17 12950360
7/24/17 12814398
7/31/17 13405187
8/7/17  13277755
8/14/17 13142375
8/21/17 12742153
8/28/17 12610817
9/4/17  12267747
9/11/17 12570075
9/18/17 12704157
9/25/17 12835948
10/2/17 12851893
10/9/17 12978880
10/16/17    13104906
10/23/17    12754018
10/30/17    13213958
11/6/17 13584642
11/13/17    13963433
11/20/17    14471672
11/27/17    16312595
12/4/17 16630000
12/11/17    16443882
12/18/17    11555299
12/25/17    12018373
1/1/18  13031876
1/8/18  13013945
1/15/18 13164137
1/22/18 13313246
1/29/18 13652605
2/5/18  13803606
2/12/18 13308310
2/19/18 14466211
2/26/18 15092736
3/5/18  15346015
3/12/18 14467260
3/19/18 14767785
3/26/18 13914271
4/2/18  14185070
4/9/18  13851028
4/16/18 13605858
4/23/18 13597999
4/30/18 13876994
5/7/18  13026270
5/14/18 13113250
5/21/18 12288727
5/28/18 12925846
6/4/18  13525010
6/11/18 12594472
6/18/18 12654512
6/25/18 12888260
```

I was able to read the data without any errors before, initially, I had 160 records & the model does not throw any error but, then for 80-20 test I removed the last 30 records and this error cropped up. Now also, if I run with all the data I don't get any error but is I run it with first 130 as 80% I get this error.

Comment: Need more information, did you convert your data into a time series object via ts()?

Comment: Yes I converted it using ts()

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: added the data & code

Comment: The answer could be found here: 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404737/241606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `auto.arima` with `seasonal = TRUE` the parameter `S` is not calibrated but taken from the frequency of the `ts` object you are providing. So in your case `S = 52.17`.

In case the frequency of the time series is not and integer, `S` is rounded to next integer so `auto.arima` takes `S = 52`.

With `S=52` and a data of length 150 it becomes difficult to calibrate a seasonal arima model: e.g if P = 2 and and all other variables are zero the first 104 observations cannot be used. I guess that is what the warning is about. You are being told that the seasonal component cannot be calibrated due to the large coefficient `S` (or due to your short data).

So either you get a longer data history, or you aggregate your data to monthly data (such that S = 12).

Comment: I can't use monthly data as my prediction is weekly. Also, I don't have a longer data history. I was able to run with 130 records and was not getting any errors, this cropped up from today, Your explanation makes sense, but I am confused, What do you suggest?

Comment: You could set the frequency 26. This is a bit artificial but would have a nice interpretation: it would mean that your seasonal effects reoccur twice a year. 
You can give it a try and if the results are satisfactory then you can go with it.

Comment: Maybe you can ask a similar question at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
The community there has a better statistic background and I think they might be able to help you a bit better.